# linearHypothesis equivalent for ols command (rms package) in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, hypothesis-test

I am trying to use "linearHypothesis" function from "car" package to test coefficients of a model estimated with "ols" from "rms" package. The function works with "lrm" objects but not with "ols" objects. Have you got any alternatives? I know that using "lm" would sort the issue but I want to use "ols" since it is easier getting clustered standard errors there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glht` from the `multcomp` package.

```
library(rms)
library(multcomp)

d <- datadist(swiss); options(datadist="d")
fit <- ols(Fertility ~ ., data = swiss)
summary(fit)

test <- glht(fit, linfct = "Agriculture = 0")
summary(test)
# Fit: ols(formula = Fertility ~ ., data = swiss, x = TRUE)
# 
# Linear Hypotheses:
#                  Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
# Agriculture == 0  -0.1721     0.0703  -2.448   0.0144 *
#   ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you use it to test differences in the coefficients of different reference levels of a category? Say

linearHypothesis(model,-1,0,1,0),0)

after fitting 

model = ols(y ~ employment,x=T,y=T)

and employment has 5 categories.

Comment: @Giovanni I don't master `linearHypothesis` and I don't understand the meaning of your example. Maybe open a new question about `glht`. But surely yes, you can test any linear hypothesis with `glht`. Have you looked at `?glht` ?

Comment: I am looking at it just now. Thanks